# Android, Image Cache is not clearing in Picasso

Tags: android, json, caching, imageview, picasso

I'm using the following code to load an image from Json into an imageView.

```
Picasso.with(Sell_Preview_Activity.this)
                .load(Httppost_Links.imagePath
                        + ConstantVariables.sellDetails_stringURL)
                .resize(size, size).centerInside()
                .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                .into(viewImage_imageView);
```

But still the cache is maintained even after the image has been edited. Can anyone please help me how I can overcome this issue.

Comment: did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can use new method of picasso

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).invalidate(file);
```

or else same as memorypolicy add networkpolicy

```
.networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
```

Comment: I tried implementing this code "Picasso.with(getActivity()).invalidate(file);" in the very next line of what I've given in question, but it didn't work. Can you please tell where I can imply this line

Comment: which line? and in your question have you used networkcache?

Comment: try to use it and check..and for more see here https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.html

Comment: Thank you so much, clearing the networkCache worked out for me.

Comment: Glad to help you happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Picasso.with(context).load(file).skipMemoryCache().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).stableKey(id).into(imageview);
```

Comment: Hi, can you please what does this stableKey(id) mean?

Comment: that is some variable. use your own variable.

Comment: use your own variable to uniquely identify the image